# Finding Content Between Two Tags

Tags: .net, regex

I have various tags such as `<nav class="filters">XXX</nav>` and `<!-- Google Tag Manager --> XXX <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->` I'd like to search and replace but haven't been able to do so. Replace with nothing at this point but I may need to replace with some text further down the line

I've tried using the below but it doesn't work. Please advise!

```
<nav class="filters">(.*?)</nav> or <nav class=\"filters\">(.*?)</nav>
```

Seems I didn't make it obvious enough but not sure how more simple it can be :-(

It seems to work if it's on one line but when on multiple like below, it doesn't

```
<nav class="filters">
STRING CONTENT
</nav>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Erm... my regex to find what I need to

Comment: What are you trying to capture? and replace with what?

Comment: <nav class="filters">CONTENT</nav> with nothing and <!-- Google Tag Manager --> XXX <!-- End Google Tag Manager --> with nothing

Comment: @JanuszJasinski, so you just want to remove them?

Comment: Yes, tags including content. I've tried <nav class=\"filters\"\>(.*?)\</nav\>

Comment: @JanuszJasinski, and you also want to remove Google tagmanager?

Comment: Google tagmanager was ok as I did a normal replace on that :-)

Comment: So, it did not capture anything? failed with an error?

Comment: Found nothing - no error

Comment: This what you want? http://regex101.com/r/gA1rD2

Comment: It doesn't work in VWD 2013 at the very least

Comment: The content is on multiple lines. Question updated

Comment: Then use the `s` modifier or it's equivalent in VWD 2013

Comment: <nav class="filters">(.*?)<\/nav>/mgs doesn't seem to work either

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If it's the multi-line question that you want to address, read [the MSDN article on regex options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and look at `Singleline` and `Multiline`.

Answer (score 0):

Janusz, these simple regexes will do what you want.

**For the first one:** search for

```
(?is)<nav class="filters">[^<]*</nav>
```

**For the second one:** search for

```
(?is)<!-- Google Tag Manager -->[^<]*<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

**Example:**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program {
static void Main() {

string resultString = null;
string s1 = @"string was here>>> <nav class=""filters"">
            STRING CONTENT
            </nav> <<< string was here";

string s2 = Regex.Replace(s1, "(?is)<nav class=\"filters\">[^<]*</nav>", "");

Console.WriteLine(s2);
Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
} // END Main
} // END Program
```

Output:

```
string was here>>>  <<< string was here
```

The `[^<]*` will eat up any number of characters that are not a `<`, including newlines, which were your problem.

With your `.*` dot-star syntax, you could also have eaten newlines, but only by setting the `(?s)` "dot matches newline" flag. But in general whenever a dot-star can be avoided by something more specific, we do so, hence the choice of `[^<]*`

Please note that the double double quotes in `""filters""` have nothing to do with the regex. You probably know this, but two double quotes is how you escape a double quote in verbatim strings.

Comment: I ended up using Notepad++

Comment: @JanuszJasinski Great, N++, why not. You used the regex I gave you?